# How do I write the audio stream to a memory buffer instead of a file using DirectShow?

Tags: c++, directshow

I have made a sample application which constructs a filter graph to capture audio from the microphone and stream it to a file. Is there any filter which allows me to stream to a memory buffer instead?

I'm following the approach outlined in an article on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375005(v=VS.85).aspx) and are currently using the `CLSID_FileWriter`  object to write the audio to file. This works nicely, but I cannot figure out how to write to a memory buffer.

Is there such a memory sink filter or do I have to create it myself? (I would prefer one which is bundled with windows XP)

Comment: What do you want to do with the memory buffer after you create it? Would a temporary file work with the Win32 temporary file APIs? IIRC that could support playback with automatic deletion when the process ends, much like a buffer.

Comment: @electronherer I'm embedding it in a document structure which is already in memory. I have thought about using a temporary file but since there is no need for it to be stored to disk at all, I'd rather avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (although not the most elegant) is to use a [Sample Grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377544(VS.85).aspx) filter followed by a [Null Renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390934(VS.85).aspx) filter to terminate the graph. This will enable you to get access to the raw media stream using the sample grabber's [ISampleGrabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376984(VS.85).aspx) interface. Once you have the samples you can do what you like with them.

Comment: Great, thanks! I really wish memory source/sink filters were available in the standard directshow/windows install.

Comment: ISampleGrabber is now deprecated.  I'd say use [IMediaSample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407001.aspx) instead, access the raw memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IMediaSample::GetPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407001(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve a pointer to the buffer's raw data.